CSS Animation for Background not covering 100% responsive height
Hey there I have this CSS code I am trying to inject into a ReadyMag project and while it is "mostly" doing what I want it will not cover odd aspect ratio browswer windows. How do I get it to cover full width and height?
<div class="colorchange"></div>

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {background: #FF85E5; left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  {background: #D8F0FB; left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {background: #EAFFE9; left:0px; top:0px;}
75%  {background: #FFFEDE; left:0px; top:0px;}
100% {background: #F3E9FF; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {background: #FF85E5; left:0px; top:0px;}
25%  {background: #D8F0FB; left:0px; top:0px;}
50%  {background: #EAFFE9; left:0px; top:0px;}
75%  {background: #FFFEDE; left:0px; top:0px;}
100% {background: #F3E9FF; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* CSS for the text */

.colorchange {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-name:myfirst;
-webkit-animation-duration:10s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
/* Standard syntax */
animation-name:myfirst;
animation-duration:20s;
animation-timing-function:linear;
animation-delay:0s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-direction:alternate;
animation-play-state:running;
}

I have tried a bunch of things to the .colorchange attributes
only width: 100% and width 100% and height 100% -- and then both max and min heights at 100% and height: 100vh;
Please advise -- thx

Did you add margin: 0; to body to avoid the default margins of the browser?

It's been about 10 years and more since any of those browsers needed a -webkit prefix.

It seems likely to me that the underlying issues is browser computed styles. Each browser has a set of styles it applies to selectors to style them in a default way. Many web developers remove those styles with something like a CSS Reset.
Adding a CSS reset into your code in the middle of development is really painful because all computed styles will be removed but many elements you've already styled will be relying on some part of those computed styles to display as you'd expect and you'd have to go back through and test all your code to ensure no visual regressions.
All of that said, I see two paths forward.

Add a CSS Reset and fix any other styles that have regressed
Remove all computed styles for the one element you're trying to style.

If you prefer the second option, here's what I'd do:

Open the page in a web inspector and look at the box model diagram for the .colorchange element
Confirm there is no margin, padding, or border for the element
If there are, remove them

Hopefully this will solve the issue for you in this specific scenario.
